# Where does Xfce store the setting for the selected desktop wallpaper file?

Tags: linux, desktop-customization, xfce

On Xfce v4.14, in what configuration file is the setting stored for the path/filename of the user-selected wallpaper image?

In 2008, the setting was stored in `~/.config/xfce4/mcs_settings/desktop.xml`.  At least in the current MX Linux implementation and several other distros I checked, the `mcs_settings` subdirectory no longer exists.  `desktop.xml` wasn't found, either, so the setting appears to have been moved to another file.  My online searches for this information are coming up empty.

I did find a configuration file buried in the `~/.config/xfce4/` path that contains wallpaper specs, but that file doesn't appear to control which wallpaper is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current standard location for the wallpaper spec in Xfce is:

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml
```

Note that what is contained in this configuration file is not a single wallpaper spec, but a collection of specs.  There is a separate spec for each monitor type and instance, and each workspace.  These are all initially set to the distro's default wallpaper.

When you change your wallpaper, only the associated instance is changed in this file.  So, for example, if your distro is installed on an external drive and you change your wallpaper on the computer it is plugged into, that setting may not be applied if you boot the drive on another computer with a different type of display.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=4317

> Assuming you're using Xfce 4.4, look in ~/.config/xfce4/mcs_settings/desktop.xml:
>
> option name="imagepath_0_0" type="string" value="/home/username/path/to/image.png"/

**I am pretty sure, it's same on 4.14 as on 4.4**

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I had found that 2008 thread.  At least as implemented in MX Linux, that path doesn't exist.  `desktop.xml` also doesn't appear to exist, so it looks like a different configuration file is currently being used to store that.  I probably should have included that in the question; I'll add it.

Comment: so try to use:  `find / -name desktop.xml ` and post the output